Python dependency error for playwright and greenlet
coming from Java world and trying to use Python with the playwright module for testing.
I'm using Python 3.13 and got a dependency error trying to install playwright using pip and a requirements.txt file that has the dependencies:
ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (greenlet)
Here on the greenlet repo I found this: greenlet provides wheels for Python 3.13 starting with version 3.1. Earlier versions will not work.
So I added greenlet 3.1 as a dependency, and now I get this:
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested greenlet~=3.1
    playwright 1.47.0 depends on greenlet==3.0.3

The problem is Python 3.13 requires greenlet 3.1. Are newer versions of Python not backward compatible? The only way I can think of to solve this is to install an older version of Python that uses an older version of greenlet to make playwright happy?

re: "The only way I can think of to solve this is to install an older version of Python that uses an older version of greenlet to make playwright happy?"
Yes, this problem can be avoided by using python 3.12.
